# How can I bring back vim-like Ctrl-W behavior in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ide, ideavim

I recently switched from pure vim to IntelliJ, and it's great. There's one thing that drives me crazy, though: `Ctrl-W` in insert mode does not behave as it does in regular vim.

For example, if I had the following code (where `|` represents my insert-mode cursor):

```
class StackOverflowExampleFactoryFactoryBuilder {
    |
}
```

and I hit `Ctrl-W`, my decade of vim usage leads to be expect the outcome will be:

```
class StackOverflowExampleFactoryFactoryBuilder {
|
}
```

However in actuality it's:

```
class StackOverflowExampleFactoryFactoryBuilder |
}
```

Is there some setting somewhere I can do to disable this line-wrapping deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1359

Comment: This was fixed in version 0.52:
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: @Jørgen please write this up as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

[Issue VIM-1359](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1359) was fixed in [version 0.52](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/CHANGES.md#052-2019-07-23) of the IdeaVim plugin:

```
0.52, 2019-07-23
----------------
// ...
- VIM-1359 Fix behavior of i_CTRL-W action
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: My answer *is* valid without the link. The issue was fixed in v0.52 of the plugin. I've quoted the relevant part of the changelog. Hope that helps.